# Having issues with nginx and docker mapping the correct folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

For whatever reason, I keep getting the default html

My docker files are here `/Users/xxx/_sites/_blah`:

```
Dockerfile
site.conf
docker-compose.yml
```

My app with the code is here `/Users/xxx/_sites/_blah/app`

Here are my files:

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx

# Change Nginx config here...
RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD ./site.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/


COPY content /var/www/html/site

COPY conf /etc/nginx

VOLUME /var/www/html/site

VOLUME /etc/nginx/conf.d/
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  php:
    container_name: pam-php
    image: php:fpm
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html/site
  nginx:
    container_name: pam-nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./app:/var/www/html/site:rw
      - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/site.conf:rw
    ports:
      - 7777:80
```

site.conf

```
    server {
    listen  80;

    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html/site;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 192.168.59.103:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

Every tutorial or block of code just doesn't work or is old.

Comment: I wonder if your volumes are not working. I'm not familiar with what a `VOLUME` does in a `Dockerfile`, but you don't need it if you have it set up in your `docker-compose.yml` file. Have you tried shelling into your two containers to see what they can see at `/var/www/html/site`?

Comment: I know in some contexts (I think the `-v` flag to `docker run`) you can't map a relative path on the host side, so try replacing `./app` with the fully-qualified path to start with. If that works I can add an answer to show how to use an `.env` file and environment variables, instead of the relative path. That approach works very nicely for me.

Comment: I did try replacing the ./app with full path. But it didn't work. 

Please do tell us about the env file. I'm new to docker.  And setting up custom environments seems to be a challenge others are having as well.

I will try the path again, perhaps something else was off.

Comment: Before I do that, since it may be the wrong approach, would you try shelling in first? Get all your containers running, then do `docker exec -it pam-php sh` (substituting the name of your container, and also the name of your shell). You can then do `ls /var/www/html/site` to see whether you can see your on-host volume. Do this for both containers.

Comment: UPDATE:

So when I bash into the docker instance, I see there are files in /var/www/html/site

But they're all root! 

I believe that may be the issue here, but I'm having trouble figuring out what user/group they should be.


Both container have the same files, and they're all root

Comment: Great, sounds like your volume is working. Inside your web server container, do `ps aux` to see what's running and under what user. What username is NginX running under?